# Find and addClass

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>text</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to do this: if found 'th' in 'first tr', addclass 'abc' to 'second tr'. Is this jQuery correct:

```
$('table tr:eq(0)').find('th').next('tr').addClass("abc");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that won't do what you expect. Try something like this:

```
$("tr:first-child:has(th) + tr:nth-child(2)").addClass("abc");
```

or more simply:

```
$("tr:first-child:has(th)").next().addClass("abc");
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be more like this:

```
$('table tr:eq(0) th').closest('tr').next('tr').addClass('abc');
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$('table tr th').parent().next('tr').addClass("abc");
```

"For every `th` in a `tr`, search for the next `tr` in it's parent and add the class 'abc' to it."

See http://jsbin.com/asiro/edit.